# having trouble connecting to Database via config.php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to follow :

[David Carr's blog tutorial](https://daveismyname.blog/blog/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php)

Reading down in comments at end of his tutorial you can see everyone having trouble creating a user for login. He explains the user and password is set
within

> /includes/config.php

It seems straightforward enough after creating the database and

tables to input the username and password at top of configuration file :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

 //database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','foo');
define('DBPASS','foo');
define('DBNAME','foo');
```

But the login form fails. I tried checking permissions and ownership to see if that would help and initially when set up database I gave ownership to 
user I am wanting to log in.

Then I checked for the config.php form to be included in php form to login.

Cannot work out what I am doing wrong within config.php form for adding user and password to effectively log in.

NB:I have since worked this out. But as it is a painfully simple answer I will let others stuck figure it out.

hint1/ You do not create user and password within mysql for login

hint2/ the user and password is created in users.php

hint3/ David Carr's simple php/mysql blog is perfect study where he's

seamlessly included all you need in one folder and has given away

the login at start of his tutorial! *doh*

Comment: Paste your login code

Comment: I might be wrong but I can't seem to find where you initialize connection to your database. Are you doing this via MySQLI?

Comment: after set up DB and tables I went to /admin/index.php and there is the input form to test login. The config.php is supposed to create connection(?)

Comment: yes mariadb on centos command line